# SAP HANA SQL Query

Tags: hana

I am trying to convert the following sas code into HANA SQL.

```
create table age_r as
        select       A.*, B.Min_HOURS as EXCLUDE_HOURS
        from         Address   A
        inner join   scope B
        on           A.Org_unit=B.Org_unit
        where        (A.Open_CASES='' or r.MAX_HOURS='')
quit;
```

Can you please tell me what would be the correct HANA SQL ?

Comment: Stack overflow isn't a code translation tool. Please do it yourself and come back if you have a problem

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,
I have almost figured out. Except in one place, the code is running fine. But the it seems the a.* is creating problem. If I give a specific column name like 
a.case_id, the query runs fine. But when I give a.* , I get the following error,

ERROR:

```
Could not execute 'create table ageing_1 as (select l.* from "BAN515"."ageing" as l inner join "BAN515"."VA_scope" as ...'
SAP DBTech JDBC: [383]: invalid identifier: B: line 7 col 8 (at pos 321)
```

ALMOST CORRECT QUERY:

```
create table ageing_1 as
(select A.* from "XYZ"."ageing" as A
inner join "XYZ"."VA_scope" as B
on A."org_unit" = B."org_unit"
where (A."open_cases"=' ' or B."Open Job"=' '));
```

Answer (score 0):

@Tanay, I created the same code you executed by replacing tables and it executed without any error

```
create table myorderitems as (
    select
    B.*
    from "SCHEMANAME"."VBAK" as A
    inner join "SCHEMANAME"."VBAP" as B
    on A."VBELN" = B."VBELN"
    where A."VBELN" = '0000000001'
);
select * from myorderitems;
```

But your error seems to point to a different line number, is it possible?
Is there any other code you did not post on your question?